Detailing seat extraction steam cleaning
Are there any industry links information regarding interior automotive detailing in regards to airbag safety.
I want to detail auto interior, and part of detail packages I have seen online include seat agitation with extraction and steam cleaning.
Would these procedures be safe for seats with side airbags?
